# Create duplicate category page with content variations

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I want to duplicate my category pages to show two versions: one with ads and one without. (I have to show clients a page without ads).

For example I want to make a version of this category without ads:

http://newslines.org/conor-mcgregor/

I tried to copy the code in the category page into a template and use that as the template for a new page, but it wouldn't show the posts.

Any advice most welcome. thank you

Comment: can you post the code you have?

Comment: Unfortunately the code is quite complex, as there is a lot of customisation on it.

Comment: okay well can you at least tell how you determine whether a user is a client or not?

Comment: I decided to try another method. Thank you for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can create an account and give those account detail to your client to login.

And whenever your client is login you can check that and don't display ad to that user. And else it will be visible to everyone.

So we dont need to duplicate categories at all.